# Android Studio: clang error: unknown argument: '-mandroid'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to build a project with NDK and cannot get rid of this error. I searched all over the google but a similiar error is only there for Xamarin. I am using Android Studio. The error is all about:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':chessClass:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Murat\WorkspaceAndroidStudio\ChessClass\chessClass\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Murat\WorkspaceAndroidStudio\ChessClass\chessClass\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=mips64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Murat/WorkspaceAndroidStudio/ChessClass/chessClass/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Murat\WorkspaceAndroidStudio\ChessClass\chessClass\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib C:/Users/Murat/WorkspaceAndroidStudio/ChessClass/chessClass/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/libgtb.so}
[mips64] Compile        : gtb <= gtb-probe.c
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-mandroid'
make: *** [C:/Users/Murat/WorkspaceAndroidStudio/ChessClass/chessClass/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/objs/gtb/gtb-probe.o] Error 1


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':chessClass:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Murat\WorkspaceAndroidStudio\ChessClass\chessClass\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Murat\WorkspaceAndroidStudio\ChessClass\chessClass\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=mips64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Murat/WorkspaceAndroidStudio/ChessClass/chessClass/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Murat\WorkspaceAndroidStudio\ChessClass\chessClass\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib C:/Users/Murat/WorkspaceAndroidStudio/ChessClass/chessClass/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/libgtb.so}
[mips64] Compile        : gtb <= gtb-probe.c
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-mandroid'
make: *** [C:/Users/Murat/WorkspaceAndroidStudio/ChessClass/chessClass/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/objs/gtb/gtb-probe.o] Error 1

    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Murat\WorkspaceAndroidStudio\ChessClass\chessClass\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Murat\WorkspaceAndroidStudio\ChessClass\chessClass\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=mips64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Murat/WorkspaceAndroidStudio/ChessClass/chessClass/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Murat\WorkspaceAndroidStudio\ChessClass\chessClass\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib C:/Users/Murat/WorkspaceAndroidStudio/ChessClass/chessClass/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/libgtb.so}
[mips64] Compile        : gtb <= gtb-probe.c
clang.exe: error: unknown argument: '-mandroid'
make: *** [C:/Users/Murat/WorkspaceAndroidStudio/ChessClass/chessClass/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips64/objs/gtb/gtb-probe.o] Error 1

    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildTaskUtils.executeBuildProcessAndLogError(ExternalNativeBuildTaskUtils.java:241)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildTask.executeProcessBatch(ExternalNativeBuildTask.java:231)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildTask.build(ExternalNativeBuildTask.java:163)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    ... 85 more


BUİLD FAILED

Total time: 2.78 secs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [this](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/5) related issue won't be fixed by the android-ndk folks:

> Openssl (1.0.2g) adds -mandroid to the compile flags. This flag is not recognized by clang (clang38: error: unknown argument: '-mandroid'). Since it's a known gcc flag, I expect other libraries would do the same.
>
> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/GNU_002fLinux-Options.html provides the details for what that flag does in gcc. I'm not sure if this belongs here or as a clang issue, but I wanted to bring up this potential compatibility problem.

.

> Talked with our clang folks. There isn't any point in supporting this flag in clang since the -target flag covers it already.
>
> At some point in the (hopefully near?) future we're going to be shipping the compilers as wrappers so that we can make sure standalone toolchains, NDK build, and gradle builds all behave the same, and those wrappers could filter out unknown flags too.

Comment: so basically removing -mandroid is ok? "There isn't any point in supporting this flag in clang since the -target flag covers it already."

Comment: Yes, I would say so. At least according to the link I pointed out to you.

Comment: I removed `-mandroid` from the configure script and it compiled just fine!