# Compiling OpenSSL for android ndk r17b

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I tried [How to build and integrate OpenSSL into your Android NDK project – Scottyab's blog](https://scottyab.com/2017/05/how-to-build-and-integrate-openssl-into-your-android-ndk-project/), but had problems with it:

Error message

```
openssl/x86_64/lib/libcrypto.a(eng_openssl.o):eng_openssl.c:function test_rc4_init_key: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
openssl/x86_64/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function close_console: error: undefined reference to 'stdin'
openssl/x86_64/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function close_console: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
openssl/x86_64/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function open_console: error: undefined reference to 'stdin'
openssl/x86_64/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function open_console: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
```

I tried [Compilation fails with android ndk r15b · Issue #3826 · openssl/openssl's comment](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/3826#issuecomment-312480563), and it did remove one of the errors, but the others were left.
[Compilation fails with android ndk r15b · Issue #3826 · openssl/openssl's comment](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/3826#issuecomment-313269094) has suggests using `--deprecated-headers`, didn't work either.

[NDK: Unified Headers issue · Issue #445 · android-ndk/ndk's comment](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/445#issuecomment-313322546) says it's resolved. I tried setting the `CFLAGS=-D__ANDROID_API__=$API` but it didn't help.

I also tried using clang as the compiler using and got

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mandroid'
```

[Android Studio: clang error: unknown argument: '-mandroid''s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43216836/1346426) has a good explanation for it.

Actually [faisal00813/openssl_for_ios_and_android: OpenSSL Library for iOS and Android](https://github.com/faisal00813/openssl_for_ios_and_android) fork uses clang as the compiler and the `-mandroid` bug is resolved, but still getting the `undefined reference to 'stdin'`

Comment: remove '-mandroid' from all the open ssl source code. I have compiled it and its generating .a files successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used [willyliu/build-openssl-android: Builds openssl 1.1.0h with android ndk r17.](https://github.com/willyliu/build-openssl-android), and it worked great. My fork [david-hoze/build-openssl-android: Builds openssl 1.1.0h with android ndk r17.](https://github.com/david-hoze/build-openssl-android) has some minor fixes